# Help me to find out the object path in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Help me to get the *target path* of an object.So that i can give *properties/methods* to that object.Actually i need the *target path* when an event occurs.like on `click/keyup/enterframe`..and so on.

```
var curinstance:Object = ev.target.valueOf();
```

In the above code i get the instance name of the particular object i cant give *properties and methods* to it.

Comment: You keep asking the same questions and getting the same answers - start taking the advice you have been given and read up on AS programming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ev.target.name gives you the path of the object.

Rob